# Does Flash Builder 4 Generated Value Objects Support Inheritance/Polymorphism?

Tags: apache-flex, inheritance, polymorphism, remoteobject, flashbuilder4

At Java side, I have

```
Interface Node
FloatLiteral implements Node
Resource implements Node
```

And DAO that provide service that returns

```
public List<Node> getAll()
```

Thus it can return FloatLiterals and Resources.

When I use Flash Builder 4 Data/Services wizard, it generates value object only for Node. If I force the wizard to generate value objects for FloatLiteral and Resource by adding the below (which will be removed after value objects are generated)

```
public List<FloatLiteral> getFloats()
public List<Resource> getResources()
```

The generated value objects seems does not build the relationship like at Java side. All are standalone classes.

Anyone have idea how to make Flex remoting support inheritance and polymorphism by using Flash Builder 4 Data/Services wizard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance is supported by remoting since it uses the mapped aliases of the classes to (de)serialize the objects. However, the Flash Builder data wizards (Fiber) do NOT support inheritance. We were also faced with this issue some time ago and decided to write our own code generator instead.

Comment: Do you know any good open source VO code generator that support Java syntax like enum, generic etc? Thanks.

Comment: GraniteDS has a code generator, but I have not used it yet: http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/4.+Code+Generation+Tools+Installation